# iframe shifts down each time iPhone is rotated

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, iframe, mobile-safari

The iframe on my page is being shifted down about 20 pixels each time iPhone is rotated.

The only content on my page is a body tag and the iframe tag, and it only seems to happen when the iframe is pointed to my game.html.

[image]

Has anyone else run into this issue or know how to troubleshoot it?

CODE:

```
<iframe id="gameiFrame" src="game.html" width="100%" height="500"></iframe>
```

UPDATE:

The iframe itself is not moving down, rather the iframe content is. The game.html file is 3rd party proprietary and obfuscated code but I know it is executing javascript to center the content on the page.

Comment: post the CSS code that you are setting for gameiFrame

Comment: We need the code for game.html to debug this...

Comment: It looks like it is the iframe content that is moving down.

Comment: i tried mak demo based on your question but i cant facing problem as you told. Here code which i tried :                       NSString *myHTML = @"<html><body><iframe id=\"gameiFrame\" src=\"http://www.brainjar.com/java/host/test.html\" width=\"100%\" height=\"200\"></iframe></body></html>";
    [wvIFrame loadHTMLString:myHTML baseURL:nil];
    
    [wvIFrame setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Comment: Have you tried removing width=100% and instead set it to a fixed value? Does it make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Lock it to the top!
A quick google search yielded this
`onLoad="if(parent.frames.length!=0)top.location='pagename.html';"`

Answer (score 0):

The content in the iFrame itself was moving down on every rotate, there really is not anything I could do about that.

As a work around I counted every rotate and moved the iFrame up 30 pixels or so for each rotation that has occurred.

Comment: There is a better way do do this. See my answer